# Need Apps Script to Copy a File(s) from my Local Hard Drive to a Google Sites Folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing an Apps Script in Google Sites (sites.google.com) and I need the script to copy a file from my local hard drive (or a server file share) to a Google Sited Folder. Can I do this? Is there some sample code? I am basically trying to do what is described here in Section 1 (Linking Google Drive Folders with Sites File Cabinet):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites

But I dont want to copy from my Google Drive to a Google Sites folder but rather my local hard drive or file server to a Google Sites Folder.

Thanks,
Todd

Answer (score 1):

You have to write an UI to that allows the visitor to the site to upload the file. 
See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/file-upload for an example.

Comment: Thank you. Is a UI "required"? To be more specific on our needs... we want to schedule an Apps Script to run each night that will take all files in a specified directory on my hard drive or file server (\\SERVER\MYDIRECTORY\) and put them on a Google Sites Folder without any user intervention. We will not be able to use a User Interface. Can this be done?

Comment: I'm afraid that cannot be done. Simply because, Google Apps Script runs on Google's servers and not on your server. You can get it to work through convoluted ways (using a database etc. ) but in any case, you'll have to write a program that runs on your server

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an older post but, i couldn't see the right answer.

Im using an additional software called "DROPIT" with "Google Drive PC Software".

So, the soft of G.Drive helps you to manage your Google Drive account in a local manner, allowing you to simply drag and drop documents from your local Hard Drive to your G. Drive account, always keeping it logged and running when Windows Starts.

By the other hand, use DropIT Software to automate whatever you want to do. (eg. move all JPG extension files from a local folder to another using. Read more about the software its very customizable and usefull.

Comment: (Not as older as it could be =) If you about dropitto.me, it is discontinued. However, you can use for example Yandex disk in webdav mode.